# Rest-client POST without a payload

Tags: ruby, post, rest-client

I am trying to POST using Rest-Client gem in Ruby, and I keep getting a return from the web service as Error 414 Unsupported Media Type, because I am setting the payload argument as ''

Example

```
RestClient.post 'https://username:password@remotesystem/api/v1/applications/44204093/publishUpdates','' ,:accept =>  'json'
```

The issue is that the web service does not want or need a payload for this resource, but the RestClient feels the need to have one specified.

Anyone know how to do a post with rest client and not have to specify a payload argument?

thanks

Comment: were you able to find a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For post I believe the method is url, payload, header

```
url = 'https://username:password@remotesystem/api/v1/applications/44204093/publishUpdates'
header = {'Accept' => 'application/json'}
RestClient.post url, {}, header
```

This is off the top of my head, but this tripped me up as well.

Comment: Sorry but that still returns a 415 Unsupported Media Type

If I run the same call using CURL it works fine. Here is a CURL example;

    [code]curl --request POST https://username:password@remotesystem/api/v1/applications/44728380/publishUpdates -v[/code]

Answer (score 0):

Gem is rest-client 1.8.0, most current stable one.
I am also getting this error
RestClient::UnsupportedMediaType: 415 Unsupported Media Type
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@caredox/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:74:in `return!'

For calling post and response is a JSON

```
RestClient.post(url,
                    {
                      :arg1 => var1
                    },
                    {:Authorization => "Bearer blahblah",
                     :content_type => :json,
                     :accept => :json
                    }
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

This started happening for me in ruby 2.4. Ruby 1.9 didn't have this problem, for the same version of rest-client. If no payload is specified in the call, the content-type header was being set to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' which caused the server to say 'No operation matching request path ...' and return '415 Unsupported Media Type'. The solution was to explicitly set content-type to nil in the call:

```
RestClient::Request.execute(:url => query, :ssl_version => 'TLSv1', :method => 'post', :headers => {'Content-Type' => nil})
```